Bounding $S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k) \left( \pi\left(\frac{n}{k}\right) - \pi(\text{gpf}(k)) \right)$
I am trying to bound the sum
$$S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k) \left( \pi\left(\frac{n}{k}\right) - \pi(\text{gpf}(k)) \right)$$
In other site, I have been given steps for a "proof" that $S(n) = O\left(\sqrt{n}\right)$, whose main sketch is below. I would need help assessing if the steps provided can lead to some rigorous and complete proof. I think that the approach could be correct, but steps are incomplete. Here it goes:
Step-by-Step Proof

Separating the Sum:
Rewrite the sum $S(n)$ as:
$S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k) \pi\left(\frac{n}{k}\right) - \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k) \pi(\text{gpf}(k))$
Bounding the First Sum:
Consider the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k) \pi\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$. The prime counting function $\pi(x)$ can be approximated by $ \frac{x}{\log x}$, but for a rigorous approach, we use the exact function.
The Dirichlet convolution of $\mu(k)$ with $\pi\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$ can be studied using the properties of $\mu(k)$. Note that $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) = 0$ for $n > 1$, which implies significant cancellations in the sum.
Bounding the Second Sum:
Now consider $\sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k) \pi(\text{gpf}(k))$. $\mu(k)$ is zero if $k$ has a repeated prime factor, leading to further cancellations.
Big-O Analysis:
We know that the prime counting function $\pi(x)$ is $O\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right)$. Thus, $$\sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k) \pi\left(\frac{n}{k}\right) = O\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k) \frac{n/k}{\log(n/k)}\right)$$

Applying Dirichlet’s hyperbola method and known bounds on sums involving $\mu(k)$, we obtain:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k) \pi\left(\frac{n}{k}\right) = O(\sqrt{n})$$
5. Second Sum Analysis:
Similarly, analyze $\sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k) \pi(\text{gpf}(k))$. Because $\text{gpf}(k)$ is generally small and the Möbius function induces significant cancellations:
$$
   \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k) \pi(\text{gpf}(k)) = O(\sqrt{n})$$
Conclusion
Combining both parts, we get:
$$S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k) \left( \pi\left(\frac{n}{k}\right) - \pi(\text{gpf}(k)) \right) = O(\sqrt{n})$$
Thanks in advance for your help!

This is an absolutely terrible proof that almost surely was written by a large language model such as ChatGPT. Steps 1–3 are trivial observations, and step 4 already has the fatal $\mu(t)$. Voting to close.

I think that the graph of $S(n)$ can be helpful to guess its asymptotic behavior.

@GregMartin agree, the "proof" is terrible, but I wanted to know if there is something usable to obtain a real proof

If creating a valid proof is the goal, I don't think it's an efficient use of time (certainly not MathStackExchange volunteers' time) to start from garbage proofs like ChatGPT's.

@GregMartin you have a point there. Indeed, the question could be simplified to include only the main sketch, so I have edited it. My intention, obviously, was not to waste anyones time, but to show the main steps provided to assess if it was worthy digging in them. Apologies if it has been more a source of trouble than helpful and useful.

I'm not trying to disparage you personally. But “show the main steps provided” is already unhelpful because those steps are absolute rubbish. Step 1 is completely trivial, Steps 2 and 3 don't even assert anything, Step 4 starts with an obviously false statement ($\mu(k)$ can't appear in an error term) and then leaps to an unsupported statement, and Step 5 is another unsupported statement. This isn't even superficially an attempt at a proof. It's word salad.

Ok, I see. If I delete the steps then the question makes no sense. I will award the bounty to @AlexRavsky excellent answer, which is already sufficient, and close the question.

The answer is negative because $S(n)$ oscillates at least as $1+\pi(n)\approx \frac n{\log n}$.
Indeed, let $n$ be a natural number. Then $S(n)=S_1(n)-S_2(n)$, where
$S_1(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k) \pi\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$ and
$S_2(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k) \pi(\text{gpf}(k))$.
Now suppose that $p\approx i\log i$ is the $i$th prime. Then
$S_2(p)-S_2(p-1)=-i$ and
$S_1(p)-S_1(p-1)=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \mu(k)S_k,$
where $S_k=\pi\left(\frac{p}{k}\right)-\pi\left(\frac{p-1}{k}\right)$ for each natural $k\le p-1$.
If $k=1$ then $\mu(k)=1$ and
$S_k=\pi\left(\frac{p}{k}\right)-\pi\left(\frac{p-1}{k}\right)=\pi(p)-\pi(p-1)=1.$
Let $k$ be any natural number such that $2\le k\le p-1$. If $\pi\left(\frac{p}{k}\right)\ne \pi\left(\frac{p-1}{k}\right)$ then there exists a prime number $q$ such that
$\frac{p-1}{k}<q\le \frac{p}{k}$, that is $p-1<kq\le p$, so $kq=p$, which is impossible because $p$ is prime. Therefore $S_k=0$.
Thus $S_1(p)-S_1(p-1)=\mu(1)S_1=1$ and
$$S(p)-S(p-1)=(S_1(p)-S_1(p-1))-(S_2(p)-S_2(p-1))=$$ $$1+i=1+\pi(p)\approx \frac p{\log p}.$$

I left the part below, based on the old answer, because it provides more details on $S_2(n)$.
Let $\mathbb P$ be the set of prime numbers. For each $p\in\mathbb P$ let $Q_p$ be the set of products of distinct prime numbers smaller than $p$. Since for any natural $k$, $\mu(k)$ is zero if $k$ has a repeated prime factor, we have
$$S_2(n) =-\sum_{p\le n,\, p\in\mathbb P} \pi(p)\sum_{q\in Q_p,\, q\le n/p} \mu(q).$$
In fact, for each natural $i$ let $p_i$ be the $i$th prime number and for each finite set $S$ of natural numbers let $\Pi(S)=\prod_{i\in S} p_i$. Then
$$S_2(n)=\sum_{S\subset \mathbb N,\, |S|<\infty, \, \Pi(S)\le n} (-1)^{|S|}\max S.$$

thanks for your great answer!
